# Find all files without broken links

Tags: linux, shell

I need to find all source files including linked files, but avoid broken links.

I have a c/c++ source code area, with some files linked to files to other directories and I want to index them using cscope. When there are broken links, cscope gives an error:

```
cscope: cannot find file /...file....
```

What I need actually is to create a clean cscope.files without broken linked files.

What I'm currently doing is:

```
find $code_path -type f -name '*.h' -o -name '*.c' -o -name '*.cpp' >> cscope.files
```

Answer (score 0):

`find` with little help from `file` to get the filetype, and `print`-ing the files that do not have broken symbolic link target:

```
find "$code_path" -type f -name '*.h' -o -name '*.c' -o -name '*.cpp' \
    -exec sh -c 'file "$1" | grep -qv broken' _ {} \; -print
```

This has the caveat of processing one file at a time.

---

if you do not have any filename with whitespace(s) or any control character(s), you can leverage `find ... -exec {} +` capability of dealing with maximum number of file(s) in one go without triggering `ARG_MAX`, and getting the desired filenames with `awk`:

```
find "$code_path" -type f -name '*.h' -o -name '*.c' -o -name '*.cpp' \
    -exec file {} + | awk '!/broken/ {print $1}'
```

---

**Side note:** Quote your variable expansions to prevent word splitting and pathname expansion from taking place on the expansion.